# I can't log in into my PC, shows grub rescue instead

Tags: boot, grubrescue, boot-partition

I have Windows 7, Windows8, and Ubuntu installed. Now, when I turn on my PC, it doesn't start and it shows "Grub rescue".

All that I could find is my Linux partition where I can find the boot files is(hd0,msdos5) And that my kernel is `vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic`.

I hope that you can help me.

Comment: try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) & use `Recommended Repair` option. Once done, it will give you a url, save it. If the problem is not resolved after reboot, post the url in your question.

Comment: @Web-E Please provide additional information adding an answer and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by this: http://www.zdnet.com/windows-7-declares-war-on-grub-4010022376/

If you have a grub2 do grub rescue as follows:

1. Prepare a Live CD or make a Live USB via http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
2. boot it up as live, do no t install anything
3. Open Terminal
4. `sudo fdisk -l`  - this should show you where the Linux is installed could be `dev/sda1`
5. `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` - this will mount you system partition
6. `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda` - should be sda if the Linux was on sda1 or sdb for sdb1 etc...
7. `sudo update-grub` - updates a grub menu

Your system should be back again. If nothing helps, try to discover it by yourselves here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD

Comment: Thank you so much, it was dificult but it work :)

Comment: Usually I have one or two live installations with me, so usually it is much easier